# C++ How do I make a counted for loop that determines which of two entered numbers is lowest, and counts up from there

Tags: c++, for-loop, counting

I'm working on a program that takes two inputted values and adds all the numbers in between them, including the entered values themselves. However, it needs to work both ways, so entering 5 first and 1 second would work exactly the same as entering 1 first and 5 second. My problem is I'm restricted to only using one loop for the whole function, which is the for loop I'm using to add up all the numbers. I can't have an if or switch statement within the loop. I'm having a very hard time figuring out a code for the program to determine which of the two numbers is lowest, and then counting up from there. This is one of the ideas I was trying to make work but obviously it's gotten me nowhere so far.

```
for (int i = x; i <= y; i++)
{
    i ? sum += i : x += y;
    count++;
}
```

Comment: Have you considered checking the two numbers first, and `swap()`ing `x` and `y` if `x` is greater than `y`?

Answer (score 3):

Use Algebra, no loops. Sum of consecutive numbers = Num of terms * (first term + last term) - Arithmetic Progression.

```
auto sum = std::abs(firstVal - secondVal + 1) * (firstVal + secondVal);
```

Comment: I need to use unsigned ints for the variables so I can't use the abs command.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use builtin functions of c++, then you can do this sort of things

```
int firstNum,secondNum;
std::cin >> firstNum >> secondNum; //inputs from the user
int sum=0; //sum initialized with 0
for (int i = std::min(firstNum,secondNum); i <= std::max(firstNum,secondNum); ++i)
{
    sum += i; //summing all the values
}
/* Thanks to the comment of  user4581301 I realized that
 *  you can  count the numbers in between the firstNum 
 * and secondNum by simple subtraction and save some time
 */
int count = std::abs(firstNum-secondNum) + 1 ; //finds the absoulte value of the difference
```

Comment: Save time on the `count++`. You can just subtract after the loop.

Comment: By the way, nice descriptive names. +1

Answer (score 0):

```
if (x > y) 
{
  int c = x;
  x = y;
  y = c;
}
for (int i = x; i <= y; i++)
{
    sum += i;
}
```

or maybe better solution:

```
int sign = (x < y) ? 1:-1;
for (int i = x; i != y + sign ; i += sign )
{
    sum += i;
}
count = (y - x) * sign + 1;
```

Comment: for counting you can just use count = y - x  + 1;

Comment: In the question, s/he can only use for loops, no if/else allowed

Comment: " I can't have an if or switch statement within the loop." It's outside. Isn't aternary operator an equivalent of if?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this without using a for loop.

```
int sumxy = x+y;
int diffxy = abs(x-y);

int sum = (diffxy+1)*sumxy/2;
```